# JS how to use object destructuring after definition

Tags: javascript, destructuring

Sorry I know this is really a dumb question, but I couldn't find the answer after a couple of rounds googling. Code looks like below:

```html
let x = 0
// After some calculation I know the obj should be:
const obj = {'x': 1 }
// Then how to destructuring assigment at this line
{ x } = obj // this is incorrect
// But if I use: x = obj.x, ESLint warns me: [eslint] Use object destructuring. (prefer-destructuring)

console.log(x);
```

So my question is how to use destructuring assignment after `x` has been defined.

Comment: I don't see a problem, `const obj = {'x': 1}; const { x } = obj;` works fine. Could you show more code?

Comment: @SamHolmes Thank you! I get the answer from your link!

Comment: @dhilt I have defined `let x = 0` before destructuring assignment. Which is different to your sample code, yours is destructuring assign on x on the fly of definition. Thank you all the same!

Answer (score 0):

The initialization and destructing should happen in the same line. If you want to set an initial value, why not use `default value` assignment.

`let { x = 0 } = obj`

Comment: My problem was I cannot know what the `obj` is when define `x`. Thanks.

Comment: @LiuWenbin_NO. you failed to mention that in your problem statement. Given your current question, this is a completely valid answer.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts OK.. But I think I have said that '// After some calculation I know the obj should be:'